# Trying to make an angularjs app, but not able to install npm. Please let me know what is this error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, visual-studio, npm, npm-install

Error message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.t
>   argets(42,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform
>   Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, either
>   click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC+
>   + Projects...". Install Visual Studio 2010 to build using the Visual Studio 201
>   0 build tools. [C:\Users\harmandeep.singh\angular-phonecat\node_modules\utf-8-v
>   alidate\build\validation.vcxproj]

Comment: do you tried to do `either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC+ + Projects...` ?

Comment: I fixed the problem by uninstalling Visual studio 2010 and installing 2015. It didn't show this error again. I guess earlier one wasn't install properly.
Thank you anyway.